# Excel How to use InStr

Tags: excel, if-statement

```vb
If InStr(1, UCase(CStr(compare_DU_ID)), "L4L", 1) >= 1 Then
    If UCase(CStr(compare_DU_ID)) = UCase(CStr(DU_ID)) Then 'If L4L in compare_DU_ID, then DU_ID definitely equals to compare_DU_ID
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date '1. Cells(y, 97) might need to change, depending on which contract date you want to update
    End If
ElseIf InStr(1, CStr(compare_DU_ID), CStr(DU_ID), 1) = 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date
ElseIf InStr(1, CStr(DU_ID), CStr(compare_DU_ID), 1) = 1 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date
End If
```

I have a problem to update the date. For instance, 1st scenario, if `CStr(DU_ID) = 1731WG` and `CStr(compare_DU_ID) = 31731WG`, then the date won't be updated. 2nd scenario, when `CStr(DU_ID) = 1392WG` and `CStr(compare_DU_ID) = 11392WG`, the date will be updated.

What do I need to adjust to the code, so that second scenario won't be changed as well.

Also, I seriously think that 11392WG will be updated is because it starts with "1", so is 1392WG. And 31731WG won't be changed is because it doesn't start with "1", which is the first value of 1731WG.

Comment: seems like just `If compare_DU_ID = DU_ID Or compare_DU_ID = Left(DU_ID) & DU_ID Then`

Comment: I suggest setting temporary variables `str1 = UCase(CStr(compare_DU_ID))` and `str2 = UCase(CStr(DU_ID))`, then rewrite your example. When programming, respect "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. It makes your code cleaner and in most cases also faster Ideally give your temporary variables some meaningful names too... This is not an answer to your specific problem but rather a general advice. Actually this is probably the most important programming guideline/rule at all.

Comment: @Slai I think the problem happen is because in 2nd scenario, `11392WG` is start with "1", which is the 1st value of `1392WG`

Comment: @V.K. Thank you for your suggestion. I am in a rush to code in this new language, but I will bare that in mind.

Comment: @JimmyHuang the `Left("1392WG") & "1392WG"` part in my example results in `"11392WG"`

Comment: @Slai I don't get it, how do you mean?

Comment: @JimmyHuang like the code in my first comment `If StrComp(compare_DU_ID,DU_ID,1)=0 Or StrComp(compare_DU_ID,Left(DU_ID) & DU_ID,1)=0 Then`

Comment: @Slai I think it won't work since that it will miss the word that start with `DU_ID`. For instance, `1392WGL2L` will be missed.

Comment: @Slai I think its a bug of InStr()

Comment: @JimmyHuang It's not, but your question might be missing some important details for more accurate answers. For example, how are `compare_DU_ID` and `DU_ID` declared and initialized.

Comment: @Slai `DU_ID = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 2).Value` and `compare_DU_ID = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 2).Value`

Answer (score 0):

You are using this version of the function

```
Public Shared Function InStr(_
  ByVal Start As Integer, _
  ByVal String1 As String, _
  ByVal String2 As String, _
  Optional ByVal Compare As Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod _
) As Integer
```

Which is fine, just note you can say instead of 1 at the end of your function `VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare` or nothing at all.

I think the problem is you expect it to be at 1 instead of >= 1.

```
If InStr(1, UCase(CStr(compare_DU_ID)), "L4L", 1) >= 1 Then
   If UCase(CStr(compare_DU_ID)) = UCase(CStr(DU_ID)) Then 'If L4L in compare_DU_ID, then DU_ID definitely equals to compare_DU_ID
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date '1. Cells(y, 97) might need to change, depending on which contract date you want to update
   End If
ElseIf InStr(1, CStr(compare_DU_ID), CStr(DU_ID), 1) < 1 Then
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date
ElseIf InStr(1, CStr(DU_ID), CStr(compare_DU_ID), 1) < 1 Then
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(y, 97).Value = Updated_Date
End If
```

Try this and please note, I've changed indentation and `=1` to `>=1` on lines 4 and 6

Comment: They are not using that version of function. They are using VBA. It is also not clear why you replace `=` with `>=`. You might be right, but it would appear to me the OP tried to express "if starts with".

Comment: @GSerg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx. There are 2 versions of InStr according to Microsoft. I never said they were NOT using VBA what implied that to you?

Comment: InStr returns the index of the match, the match is located at 2. If InStr has no match it returns either 0 or -1.

Comment: That is VB.NET. The OP is using [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811.aspx) because the question is tagged `excel`.

Comment: @JReid According to your suggestion, both scenario will be updated. But I don't want both scenario to be updated.

Comment: It's an else-if only one of them would execute. But are you trying to express this truth-table e.g. DU_ID=1731WG cmpDU_ID=31731WG UPDATE=FALSE; DU_ID=1392WG cmpDU_ID=11392WG Update=TRUE?

Comment: @JReid No, both should be FALSE

Comment: Should've asked that first, if both are to be false I would use `< 1` see answer edit.

Comment: @JReid Nahh, If I use `<1` then both scenario will be updated. I really think that 2nd scenario will be updated is because they both start as `1`

Comment: Okay, let's think  
e.g. InStr(1, "31731WG", "1731WG", 1) = 2, InStr(1, "1731WG", "31731WG", 1) = 0. InStr(1, "11392WG", "1392WG", 1) = 2, InStr(1, "1392WG", "11392WG", 1) = 0. All of these combinations should be **no update** ?

Comment: @JReid yes, all should not be updated. The desire result is compare_DU_ID is started as DU_ID. For instances, If DU_ID is `1731WG`, then the `compare_DU_ID` I want could be, `1731WGL2L` or `1731WG` instead `11731WG`. If it confuse you, please feel free to ask.

Comment: @JReid Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @JimmyHuang sorry for the delay give me a minute, what you want is very possible.

Comment: @JReid No rush, many thanks in advances! Am stuck in this shit for whole day

Comment: `InStr(1, "1731WG", "1731WGxxxx", 1) = 0`, `InStr(1, "1731WGxxxx", "1731WG", 1) = 1`. To get an update on either of these is what you originally posted, **I think you need to check your input data**; Use your original code and the @V.K. suggestion of `str1 = UCase(DU_ID)` and `str2=UCase(compare_DU_ID)` and step through the code using F8. Make sure str1 and str2 are as expected. You can also do `int1 = instr(1, str1, str2, 1)` and `int2 = instr(1, str2, str1, 1)` to get even better information.

Comment: @JReid It still not working, I literally think its a bug of InStr()